# page navigation in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm new to jsp and want to navigation from one page to the next one using the servlet

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    String destination = "/WEB-INF/pages/result.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
request cannot be resolved to a variable
response cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: What do you think the `init` method does? What do you think `forward` does? What are `request` and `response`?

Comment: read up on the lifecycle of a servlet.  Hint `doGet`

Comment: you need to use the resp.. and req.. variable that are passed as parameters to ur doGet or doPost /// do try resp.sendRedirect("abc.jsp");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use init() for request dispatch , do as follows .

```
  @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");

        resp.sendRedirect("abc.jsp");
// you can replace it with RequestDispatcher also
    }
```

---

method ***init*** of GenericServlet will get called before the doGet method of class HttpServlet

**GenericServlet does not support request dispatch(page navigation in simple terms)**

[Designing a generic servlet which handles request dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176494/designing-a-generic-servlet-which-handles-request-dispatching)

And the reply to that

> Nowadays web programmers don't write this kind of code themselves. These use web frameworks like Struts or JSF or Spring (if you're a Java programmer) which provide elegant implementations of dispatching requests, of mapping from requests to classes that implement the requests. And much, much more.